# Why Material UI Alert Dialog background is black?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I trying to show an alert dialog whenever a user is tapping on a button, the button is called inside a material ui DataGrid, the problem i'm facing right now is that the background of the alert dialog is black when it should be transparent.

**This how the button clicked on looks on the App (Circled by green)**

[image]

**This how the dialog looks like when it's open, with it's black background**

[image]

**The Code:**

```
export default function PostList() {


const columns = [
    { field: "_id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Link to={"/post/" + params.row._id}>
              <button>Edit</button>
            </Link>
            <DeleteOutlineIcon
              onClick={handleClickOpenAD}
            />
            
            <Dialog
                    open={openAD}
                    onClose={handleCloseAD}
                    aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description">
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                    {"Are you sure you want to delete this post?"}
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleCloseAD}>Disagree</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row._id)} autoFocus>
                        Agree
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
            
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
return (
<>             
            <DataGrid
                rows={posts}
                getRowId={(row) => row._id}
                disableSelectionOnClick
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={8}
                checkboxSelection
                />
</>

):

};
```

Comment: You didn't post your styles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the styling with `BackdropProps`, so the code will look like:

```
export default function PostList() {
  const columns = [
    { field: "_id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Link to={"/post/" + params.row._id}>
              <button>Edit</button>
            </Link>
            <DeleteOutlineIcon
              onClick={handleClickOpenAD}
            />

            <Dialog
              open={openAD}
              onClose={handleCloseAD}
              aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
              aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description">
              BackdropProps ={{ style: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }, }}
              <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                {"Are you sure you want to delete this post?"}
              </DialogTitle>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleCloseAD}>Disagree</Button>
                <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row._id)} autoFocus>
                  Agree
                    </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>

          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <DataGrid
        rows={posts}
        getRowId={(row) => row._id}
        disableSelectionOnClick
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={8}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </>

  )

};
```

Comment: it worked, thank you. Adding to your answer I used: backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.1)'

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I found something interesting. In my case when you click the button for some reason it opens the backdrop as many times as the number of buttons in the data grid.

Here I have 11 buttons so 11 backdrops opened:
[image]

And here is just one button:
[image]

So there must be some conection between all buttons and the onClick method that is opened on all buttons at the same time

#### Edit:

I found out that you shouldn't put dialog inside the datagrid. Insted you should put it under the datagrid table and pass the needed values from the datagrid threw state like so:

```
  const [openUserDialog, setOpenUserDialog] = useState(false);
  const [deleteRowId, setDeleteRowId] = useState<string>("");

...

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "",
      headerName: "Akcje",
      width: 350,
      sortable: false,
      filterable: false,
      hideable: false,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: theme.colors.blue01_active,
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              // return navigate(urlOperator.ordersDetails);
            }}
          >
            Edytuj
          </Button>

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            style={{
              marginLeft: "10px",
              backgroundColor: "red",
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setOpenUserDialog(true);
              setDeleteRowId(params.row.id);
            }}
          >
            Usuń
          </Button>
          

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            style={{
              marginLeft: "10px",
              backgroundColor: "green",
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              // return navigate(urlOperator.ordersDetails);
            }}
          >
            Zmień hasło
          </Button>
        </>
      ),
    },

...

return (
    <UsersContainer>
      <StyledTable
        // getRowId={(row) => row?.numer_zamowienia}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        // pageSize={5}
        // rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        // autoHeight
        autoPageSize
        // onRowClick={() => navigate(url.operatorOrdersDetails)}
      />
      
      <StyledDialog
            open={openUserDialog}
            setOpen={setOpenUserDialog}
            confirmFunction={() =>
              // DeleteUser.mutate({
              //   id_uzytkownik: deleteRowId
              // })
              console.log(deleteRowId)
            }
            dialogContent="Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć tego użytkownika?"
          />
    </UsersContainer>
  );
};
```

and this prevents it from opening multiple times in my case

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33885025)

Comment: I hope now it adds something to the table. Maybe alternative answer of some sort

Comment: thanks a lot. This answer actually fixed my issue. I had a modal rendered inside the data grid and it had been rendered as the same number of buttons. Removing it from the grid fixed the issue.